# Fetch address not aligned on word boundary (MIPS)

Tags: assembly, alignment, mips, runtime-error

Any ideas why I'm getting an alignment error? The error happens when executing `la      $t0, mainF`, even though the similar line `la      $t0, mainB` executes just fine. This is my first time coding in MIPS so I did some research and have a vague idea of what the address alignment means, but the compiler doesn't even get to the part where I add 4 before throwing me this runtime exception.

```
.data

mainF:
    .byte   1
mainB:
    .byte   1

mainN:
   (has '.word's, generic tests for the program itself)

newline:
    .asciiz "\n"
textFw:
    .asciiz "The integers in order:\n"
textBw:
    .asciiz "The integers in backwards order:\n"        

.text        

main:
    # Function prologue 
    addiu   $sp, $sp, -24        # allocate stack space -- default of 24 here
    sw      $fp, 0($sp)          # save caller's frame pointer
    sw      $ra, 4($sp)          # save return address
    addiu   $fp, $sp, 20         # setup main's frame pointer

    # Put mainF into $s0
    la      $t0, mainF
    lw      $s0, 0($t0)

    # Put mainB into $s1
    la      $t0, mainB
    lw      $s1, 0($t0)

         ...
```

Comment: Hold your horses, I didn't realize that it didn't show the line numbers. I pointed it out. Better? Even explaining why it might be throwing me that error would help. (This is why I hesitate to use help forums. Nobody wants to help.)

Comment: OK, I rewrote your question to demonstrate how it could be written to make it easy to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have the following declarations:

```
mainF:
    .byte   1
mainB:
    .byte   1
```

Assuming that `mainF` gets assigned the address `0`, `mainB` will get assigned the address `1`. Since the address `1` is clearly not word-aligned (i.e. 1 is not a multiple of 4), attempting to load it will cause an exception.

Comment: In MIPS words are 4-sized (multiple of 4)

Comment: OHHH. derpy derp! Load byte, not load word. Well that would make a lot of sense. Thanks!